# Mixing green (EV) ssl certificate with non EV certificate

Tags: tls, certificates

We have a green (EV) SSL certificate for our site and images are fetched from the same domain (https). Currently we are planning to change the images domain (for performance issues) and put them in a different domain with a different ssl certificate. In order to reduce costs we are thinking if acquiring a standard certificate (not EV) for this CDN content (for the images). In that case our page will have an EV certificate but images would be fetched from a non EV certificate.

Will this -mixing of EV and non EV certificates- remove our green status from the browser (like fetching content from http connection inside an https page)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not affect the EV status displayed in the browser's address bar.  The EV status is based only on the certificate presented for the page itself.  (You will, of course, not have EV displayed if you have mixed content or invalid certificates presented, but using a cheaper cert on images.yourdomain.tld should not be a problem.)

Comment: Thanks David. Are you sure this won't affect the browser status? Are there any docs where this can be verified?

Comment: I tested it experimentally.  The page at https://www.thawte.com/resources/getting-started/extended-validation-ssl-faq/ (an EV page) sources resources from several other sites which do not have EV certs, including JS from https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js.

Comment: From what I see, they also fetch an image (tracking image _utm.gif) from google which does not have an EV. Thanks again David!